# Counting Word Frequency (most significant words) in a String, excluding keywords

Tags: vb.net, linq, count, word-count, word-frequency

I would like to count the frequency of words (excluding some keywords) in a string and sort them DESC. So, how can i do it?

In the following string...

```
This is stackoverflow. I repeat stackoverflow.
```

Where the excluding keywords are

```
ExKeywords() ={"i","is"}
```

the output should be like

```
stackoverflow  
repeat         
this
```

P.S. NO! I am not re-designing google! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string input = "This is stackoverflow. I repeat stackoverflow.";
string[] keywords = new[] {"i", "is"};
Regex regex = new Regex("\\w+");

foreach (var group in regex.Matches(input)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(c => c.Value.ToLowerInvariant())
    .Where(c => !keywords.Contains(c))
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.Count())
    .ThenBy(c => c.Key))
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
}
```

Comment: What if this is a REALLY LARGE STRING (say 12,000 words) would Regex still be the right approach?

Comment: @discorax Try it! To split a large string on word boundaries, Regex should be just as efficient as a naive custom implementation. You might get better performance from a custom parser but I doubt it's worth the effort. For large input length, n, it's the performance of Linq that may ber the limiting factor. However I have faith that Linq is reasonably well optimized so I suspect the producedure described above is O(nk). If the number of keywords is much larger (e.g. >4), it would be better to put them in a dictionary making the overall time complexity O(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "This is stackoverflow. I repeat stackoverflow.";
string[] notRequired = {"i", "is"};

var myData =
    from word in s.Split().Reverse()
    where (notRequired.Contains(word.ToLower()) == false)
    group word by word into g
    select g.Key;

foreach(string item in myData)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```